# RubyPython doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, python-2.7, ubuntu, digital-ocean, rubypython

I'm having a problem with my Rails application in production, RubyPython won't run; I get the following error:

```
RubyPython::InvalidInterpreter: An invalid interpreter was specified.
```

I'm using ruby 2.3.0, the python version is 2.7.6 (CPython). It's running on an ubuntu 14.04 server.

It works fine locally on my Mac.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the ubuntu server has the same version of ruby and python installed?

Comment: I've tried it multiple times including setting the python path explicitly. 

In Rails console I have checked the python version to make doubly sure. Additionally I've tried with version 2.7.6 and 2.7.10 and both times I get the same error.

Comment: there's a good chance this is an issue with your particular hosting provider. Different issues are going to arise depending on where you deploy to. By the way, if you add a tag to your question specifying which company's servers you're deploying to, representatives from that company have a better chance of finding your question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the tags to reflect this.

Comment: I may have given explanation for this in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38408460/5781248) for a similar case.