# Ruby 2.1.5 and RubyPython 0.6.3- RubyPython::InvalidInterpreter: An invalid interpreter was specified

Tags: python, ruby, rubypython

I'm trying to use RubyPython on Debian 8 and have been unable to. `RubyPython.start` always raises an `InvalidInterpreter` exception. I've tried specifying the python interpreter executable but it doesn't matter. The snipped below shows my versions and attempting to start it from pry

```
rubypython (0.6.3)
adrew@bunny:~$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
adrew@bunny:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
adrew@bunny:~$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
adrew@bunny:~$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'rubypython'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> RubyPython.start
RubyPython::InvalidInterpreter: An invalid interpreter was specified.
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython.rb:67:in `block in start'
[3] pry(main)> RubyPython.start(:python_exe => "/usr/bin/python2.7")
RubyPython::InvalidInterpreter: An invalid interpreter was specified.
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython.rb:67:in `block in start'
```

Answer (score 1):

I run `strace -ff -o /tmp/pry.txt pry` to see what happens when `require rubypython` and `RubyPython.start` are entered. There was lines like

```
stat("/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so", 0x7ffd2bf4cde0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

meaning that rubypython code was trying to locate python library. What was absent was a successful `stat` for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so file.

I modified file ~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython/interpreter.rb

```
if ::FFI::Platform::ARCH != 'i386'
   @locations << File.join("/opt/local/lib64", name)
   @locations << File.join("/opt/lib64", name)
   @locations << File.join("/usr/local/lib64", name)
   @locations << File.join("/usr/lib64", name)
   @locations << File.join("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", name)
```

where the last line is what I inserted. After this `RubyPython.start` returned `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `RubyPython` to `0.6.4` versions has resolved this issue for me.